# Set composer not to auto update/upgrade packages

Tags: php, npm, composer-php

In npm config settings, you can disable package auto update:
`npm config set save-exact=true`

I don't want for packages to be auto updated/upgraded.

Is there a way to do the same in composer?
When I requre a dependency :
`composer require nikic/php-parser`

This:
`{ "require": { "nikic/php-parser": "^4.0" }}`

to be like this:
`{ "require": { "nikic/php-parser": "4.0" }}`

Comment: First off, why? Pretty much all big composer packages use semantic versioning, so it shouldn't matter if you're on 4.0 or 4.153. And secondly, you provided the answer to your own question with the last example.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **composer.lock**:

> ...running install when a composer.lock file is present resolves and
>   installs all dependencies that you listed in composer.json, but
>   Composer uses the exact versions listed in composer.lock to ensure
>   that the package versions are consistent for everyone working on your
>   project. As a result you will have all dependencies requested by your
>   composer.json file, but they may not all be at the very latest
>   available versions (some of the dependencies listed in the
>   composer.lock file may have released newer versions since the file was
>   created). This is by design, it ensures that your project does not
>   break because of unexpected changes in dependencies.

See more here https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-with-composer-lock